# What is a reasonable metric for a "long running" task in Android

Tags: android

For context, I was reading through the comparison of threading mechanisms in Android found on [this very good blog post](http://techtej.blogspot.com.es/2011/03/android-thread-constructspart-4.html) by Tejas Lagvankar. In this post, and in many other posts and even areas of the Android documentation, "long running" task is used over and over but I have not once seen a real definition of what qualifies a task as long running.

Given that we have to take into account different device capabilities based on an applications API level and other supported qualifiers, what is a lower bound for a qualifying a task as "long running". (preferably in a unit of measurement such as milliseconds).

Comment: As a note, my current metric has always been observation. I load the app on a specific config and observe whether there is a slow down. As well, I will use basic classification (such as if a task is making a database call, or http) to categorize tasks as long running.

Comment: I would say long running is a task that does not end instantly, as well as with a duration that can possibly vary for external reasons.

Comment: long running task is anything that keeps the UI thread from preforming at its best aka causes jank, stutter, freeze etc in the app.

Comment: A long running task is something that can potentially block your main thread for more than a 100ms, which is perceived by users as a stutter at UI level.

Comment: @njzk2 I see your point, but I am pretty sure nothing ends instantly and every operation takes some bound of time to execute. Maybe a better definition would be any operation that does not take a constant time? but even that is too vague I think.

Comment: @stevebot: there are mostly 2 cases: a/ operations that can be longer due to external reasons (i/o, for instance) and b/ operation that are long per se. heavy computations, image processing, large amount of data to handle. There is no quantification for this, but you should recognize them when you see them, or when your application slows down and stutters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have not once seen a real definition of what qualifies a task as long running

To a large extent, it would depend upon circumstances. Moreover, you are assuming that everyone using the term "long running" is doing so in the same way.

> what is a lower bound for a qualifying a task as "long running"

IMHO, that cannot really be answered in the abstract.

So, for example:

- In the context of avoiding "jank" (dropped frames), I consider "long running" to be any callback that takes more than about 1ms. Many of our callbacks need to be invoked as part of UI rendering, and if the total of them take too long, we may drop a frame (i.e., not update the screen when an update should have occurred). In practice, if you're not dropping frames, the exact threshold of "long running" is up to you, though mathematically it clearly will have to be decidedly less than 16ms.
- In the context of a thread/`AsyncTask`, forked by an activity, winding up being pointless due to the activity being destroyed (e.g., BACK button), I would consider "long running" to be on the order of hundreds of milliseconds.
- In the context of being at risk of process termination interrupting your background work -- the threshold when to consider using a service if you really need the work to complete -- I would consider "long running" to be about a second.
- In the context of being at risk of the device falling asleep, and therefore needing to consider a `WakeLock` to keep the CPU rolling, I would consider "long running" to be about 15 seconds, as that is the lowest inactivity timeout that the user can specify. And that assumes that the user is the one triggering this particular piece of background work; in other scenarios (e.g., `AlarmManager`, GCM message), you'll need a `WakeLock` for anything.
- And so on.

And while there's some math behind my choices, in the end, they are my choices, and other Android experts might have others.

Comment: I found this answer most helpful because of the rough metrics for different contexts and that there is some basic reasoning behind these rough metrics. I am not taking this as fact, but as a guide for how to reason about the run time of tasks.

Answer (score 2):

Android will declare "Application Not Responding" or ANR if the main thread is blocked for more than 5 seconds.  In reality, users notice delays as small as 100ms, so that's a "worst case" kind of starting point.  If your operations can block in any way (file I/O, image decode, network access, etc.) then you should defer to a bg thread.

Comment: Users can notice delays lower than 100ms. Dropped frames (at the 60fps rate) are possibly perceptible, particularly to people who are attuned to notice such things, and particularly in situations where there is a ready point of comparison (e.g., stutter in scrolling).

Comment: A fair point, thanks.  Certainly for any type of gaming or animation 60fps is the definite benchmark to hit.

Answer (score 2):

I would not try to define long running tasks by some amount of time, but rather by what this task is all about. You can do file I/O operations on UI thread successfully, because in your measurements they take few ms, but it might happen that I/O will block and your code will cause ANR. Another example is when you parse json data, if its small then it will be quick, but if it gets larger then it might also cause ANR, or maybe even OOM (Out Of Memory) exception. So I suppose its safier to categories long running tasks by looking at what such task is doing and thinking of how it scales - what happens if data gets larger.

To be safe always do I/O, data parsing/processing, network communication (here actually you have no choice) in worker threads.